# Jboss 6 throwing "javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot obtain destination for /UPCServiceLayer/upcLineOfBusinessService

Tags: jboss, cxf

I am using Jboss6 to deploy my webservices developed using CXF.

Since Jboss6 already bundled with CXF i am not using any cxf jar files inside my application.

When i try to access my wsdl file after deployment i am getting the following exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot obtain destination for: /UPCServiceLayer/upcLineOfBusinessService
    org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.ServletControllerExt.findDestination(ServletControllerExt.java:111)
    org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.ServletControllerExt.invoke(ServletControllerExt.java:165)
```

The following is my jbossws-cxf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:../upc-spring-dao.xml"/>
    <jaxws:endpoint id="UpcLineOfBusinessServiceImpl"
        address="/upcLineOfBusinessService">
        <jaxws:implementor>
            <ref bean="upcLineOfBusinessService"></ref>
        </jaxws:implementor>
        <jaxws:invoker>
            <bean class="org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.InvokerJSE" />
        </jaxws:invoker>
    </jaxws:endpoint>

</beans>
```

Please help me

Comment: I found this website https://community.jboss.org/thread/161037 after i search in google . But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `address="/upcLineOfBusinessService"` with `address="/UPCServiceLayer/upcLineOfBusinessService`?